# How to do t-test of raitos (two pairs of data) in R?

Tags: r, math, statistics, p-value

I have a dataframe of five columns,something like this:

[image]

I want to do t-test of A2/A1 vs B2/B1. One method I can think about is first calculte the ratios and make a new column `C=A2/A1` and `D=B2/B1`. Then do t-test of C vs D. But is this the correct way to do so? Or if there is another way to use the original data for comparison?
Thanks!

Comment: Seems good, what is it that bothers you? Do you have many more columns in your actual data?

Answer (score 0):

This will perform a paired t-test.

```
text="Gene A1 A2 B1 B2
gene1 100 20 2 20
gene2 10 200 2 200
gene3 10 2 2 2"
df=read.table(text=text, header=TRUE)
df[,"C"]=df[,"A2"]/df[,"A1"]
df[,"D"]=df[,"B2"]/df[,"B1"]
t.test(df[,"C"], df[,"D"], paired=TRUE)
```